# Publishing while working for a drug regulatory agency

Tags: publications

I am a recent MD-PhD graduate in the field of clinical pharmacology. While searching for post-doc positions (which are quite rare in my country), I came across several job offers from a drug regulatory agency. I would meet their profile requirements.

Although not my first choice, I am considering this option until I find a suitable post-doc position. Of course during my time at the drug regulatory agency, I would keep a link with academia with my current research group and would like to continue publishing (on topics not directly related to pharmacology).

Could it be a issue for publishing if an author has an affiliation from a drug regulatory agency? Would this take away some credit to the paper? I am asking this question as I understand that these agencies may be associated with some controversies (1).

*Selected reference: (1) Carpenter, D. P. (2010). Reputation and Power: Organizational image and pharmaceutical regulation at the FDA. Princeton University Press.*

Comment: Note that some companies will contractually prohibit publishing by employees without approval.

Comment: The answer will depend on the particular agency and its policies.  It might for example be the policy that any publication requires approval by the agency but that publications not related to your work for the agency are commonly approved without difficulty.